# Is it possible to stretch items while they are baseline in Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please take a look at my code below;

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.Window__caption {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Window__title {
  margin: auto auto auto 5px;
  cursor: move;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.Window__buttons {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

.Window__maximize-button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.Window__minimize-button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.Window__close-button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f00;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Window__caption">
<span class="Window__title">My First Window</span>
<button class="Window__buttons Window__minimize-button">−</button>
<button class="Window__buttons Window__maximize-button">☐</button>
<button class="Window__buttons Window__close-button">⨉</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Screenshot of my code;

[image]

As you can see, I have a title and three control buttons with different heights. What I want is that to stretch all flexbox items vertically while they are baseline. Is it possible to do this?

UPDATE:

The following picture is when align-item is "baseline";

[image]

And the next one is when align-item is "stretch";

[image]

It seems the glyphs are aligned but they are not. Just play in browers to see the difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "strech while they are baseline" ? Isn't `align-items:strech` what you want ?

Comment: @niiwig No, this is not my question. align-items: stretch and align-items: baseline work perfect separately. What I want is to have both of them together

Comment: So how should this appear then. What are you expecting?

Comment: @Paulie_D If I use align_items:stretch for flexbox containter, the buttons are not aligned on the main axis although their heights are the same and stretched. On the other hand, if I use align_items: baseline, they are aligned but their heights are different.

Comment: Then this is a font issue...if the glyphs aren't centered in the font-block there's probably nothing you can do.

Comment: maybe with `align-self: stretch;` on `.Window__buttons`

Comment: Could you not make the children flex and then just centre their content: http://jsfiddle.net/gohrj95v/

Comment: @Paulie_D whay do you recommend to have same height for buttons in this case? As you said, it seems the glyphs are the problems. They changed the height of buttons

Comment: @Pete justify-content does center the glyphs inside the inner-flex but this is not what I want. I want all glyphs and title to have baseline align together.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "stretch" does mean exactly, but I tried;

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.Window__caption {
  display: flex;
  height: 20rem;
  align-items: baseline;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Window__title {
  margin: 0 auto auto 5px;
  cursor: move;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
}

.Window__buttons {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

.Window__maximize-button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.Window__minimize-button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.Window__close-button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f00;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Window__caption">
<span class="Window__title">My First Window</span>
<button class="Window__buttons Window__minimize-button">−</button>
<button class="Window__buttons Window__maximize-button">☐</button>
<button class="Window__buttons Window__close-button">⨉</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tell me if this is not what you wanted it.

-- UPDATE --

I think this is what you really want it :>

It looks like the glyphs are not aligned in center, but I think that is an issue of glyphs itselves.

If you want to check the align of the glyphs, delete `justify-content: center;` inside of `.btn'. you could see it will change slightly.

```js
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .container {
      width: 100%;  height: 10rem;
      display: flex;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .title, .filter, .button-wrap {
      display:flex;  flex-flow: column;  justify-content: center;
    }
    .filter {
      flex-grow: 1.1;
    }
    ul, ul li {
      list-style: none;  list-style-type: none;
      display: flex;  flex-flow: row;
    }
    .btn {
      display: flex;  flex-flow: column;  justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <span class="title">My First Window</span>
      <div class="filter"></div>
      <div class="button-wrap">
        <ul>
          <li><button class="btn">−</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn">☐</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn">⨉</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not my answer. Stretch means to fill the available height of container. In my case, I want to have a header with three control buttons with the same height (streched) and also baseline aligned.

Comment: + If you want to the whole content goes to the top, then remove `justify-content: center;` that inside of `.title, .filter, .button-wrap`.